# Python, returning a tuple of tuples into locals inside a function

Tags: python

```
t = (('page',1),('count',25),('skip',0))

def get_arguments(t):
 page = 1
 count = 25
 skip = 0
```

Basically, what's best way to iterate over the tuple and set these arguments in
my function like the example?

Comment: The best way is don't, use a dict with those strings as keys instead.

Comment: Is there any specific reason why not to use keyword arguments?

Comment: don't name a variable 'tuple'

Comment: I updated the question, I should have caught that.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `**kwargs`:

```
t = (('page',1),('count',25),('skip',0))
arguments = dict(t)

def get_arguments(page, count, skip):
    #page = 1
    #count = 25
    #skip = 0

#call your function with
get_arguments(**arguments)
```

And don't name the variable as **tuple**.

Answer (score 0):

```
tupleData = (('page',1),('count',25),('skip',0))

def get_arguments(tupleArg):
   page, count, skip = zip(*tupleArg)[1]
   print page, count, skip

get_arguments(tupleData)
```

**Output**

```
1 25 0
```

Comment: What if `page`, `count`,.. were passed in different order?

Comment: @hcwhsa For this simple, single case, wouldnt this be enough?

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_arguments(page,count,skip):
     print page, count, skip

get_arguments(page=1, count=25, skip=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
page, count, skip = [t[1] for t in tuple]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tupleData = (('page',1),('count',25),('skip',0))

class DottedDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, *a, **k):
        super(DottedDict, self).__init__(*a, **k)
        self.__dict__ = self

def get_arguments(tupleArg):
   d = DottedDict(tupleArg)
   print d.page, d.count, d.skip

get_arguments(tupleData)
```

In principle, a normal `dict` would work as well if you do `d['page']` etc. instead, but the dotted access is even shorter.

Comment: In python3.3+ You can use a `SimpleNamespace` instance instead of y subclassing `dict`: `d = SimpleNamespace(); s.__dict__.update(tuple_arg)`.

Comment: @Bakuriu That was new to me, thanks. It seems you can do as well `d = typees.SimpleNamespace(dict(tuple_arg))` in one step.

Comment: No, you have to unpack the dictionary: `SimpeNamespace(**dict(tuple_arg))`. Passing in a `dict` I get a `TypeError: no positional arguments expected`.